# Send cookies to another page jto load div content with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the below code to load a div content from Rezults2.php page into my page.

```
$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php #hotel-list> *");
```

How can i send the same `$_GET` cookies received in my page to Rezults2.php also ?

Or how can i insert the link attributes into my code

```
$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php?var=variable&etc=etc #hotel-list> *");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do Ajax Requests to achieve the required purpose for sending and getting information.

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'page.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            variable : $('#id').val()
        },
success: function(data){
   $.each(data.variable, function() {
    //do things here.... with return data
   })
}
})
```

page.php

```
<?

 //Code to do php things

?>
```

Comment: How can i insert the link attributes into my code

$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php?var=variable&etc=etc #hotel-list> *");

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#hotel-list").load("Rezults2.php #hotel-list>",{'path': 'scotland'});
```

Rezults2.php

```
<div id="hotel-list">
    <?php
        if(!empty($_REQUEST['path'])) { 
// i used $_REQUEST because it receives the data from POST or GET.
            $path = $_REQUEST['path'];
          echo $path;
            }

    ?>
</div>
```

[Use Jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)